# How can I change a defcustom variable that has a lambda :set function without customize?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use org-journal and every time it updates, the fact that the journal directory is hard coded causes me to be unable to set deadlines on other tasks until I fix the journal location. Here is what that function looks like:

```
;;;###autoload
(defcustom org-journal-dir "~/Documents/journal/"
  "Directory containing journal entries.
  Setting this will update auto-mode-alist using
  `(org-journal-update-auto-mode-alist)`"
  :type 'string :group 'org-journal
  :set (lambda (symbol value)
         (set-default symbol value)
         (org-journal-update-auto-mode-alist)))
;;;###autoload
```

Is there a way to set **org-journal-dir** from my init file without using customize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following in your .emacs file (after modifying the directory, of course).  It will set the `org-journal-dir` without requiring you to go through the customize rigamarole.

```
(require 'org-journal)
(setq org-journal-dir "~/your/journal/dir/")
```

Comment: I'd swear that I tried that already (I actually just un-commented out this exact line), but whatever I did before didn't work so it must have been different.